# How to download from firebase storage string written by putString() in web application

Tags: download, textarea, firebase-storage

I am using firebase storage to store notes. I am writing the notes using the ref.putString() API. when selected by the user, I would like to show the string in my note page, I already have the reference and download URL. I couldn't find any example for this kind of downloading. I found only img downloading into  tag. I couldn't find example for downloading a string into a textarea or other method.

Any idea?

Comment: Great thanks, I'll check it out soon.

Comment: Hi, Thanks again for your answer. I was trying to use the ionic suggestion and define proxies (I am trying to read from firebase):   "proxies": [{
      "path": "/v0",
      "proxyUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0"
  }]      and it doesn't work. any idea what I have missed?

Comment: I am still getting: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access